# Batery overheating

Tags: overheating

I have a Samsung A8, last night i put it on charge, this morning while checking my phone, batery was completely down and showing an overheating signs. It doesn't allow charging.
What can I do to fix the problem?
Does that mean that my phone is completely HS?

Thanks for your answers

Maria

Comment: Try with a different usb cable/ adapter /  battery. What is  **completely HS**?  Please don't use slang and while you fix that edit your post to fix other grammatical errors